# Why can I call array.some() but not array.every() with union array types?

Tags: arrays, typescript

So, imagine I have a (dumb) function like this:

```js
function doSomething(input: number|string): boolean {
  if (input === 42 || input === '42') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Why am I allowed to call `array.some()` like this:

```js
function doSomethingWithArray(input: number[]|string[]): boolean {
  return input.some(i => doSomething(i));
}
```

But not `array.every()` like this:

```js
function doEverythingWithArray(input: number[]|string[]): boolean {
  return input.every(i => doSomething(i));
}
```

Which gives me this error:

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type '{ (predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): this is S[]; (predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

I don't understand the difference. In my mind either both should work, or neither.
What am I missing?

Note that `doSomething()` accepts `number|string` as its argument, so it should work with every element of `number[]|array[]`, like it does for `array.some()`, shouldn't it?

Comment: What's weird is that they have exactly the same signature.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - `every` has a type predicate while `some` does not. The `predicate` in `every` is also generic. That's the difference here.

Comment: @TobiasS. That's weird, in theory they have the same predicate:
`every(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean;`
and:
`some(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean;`

Comment: @TobiasS. yeah, I missed the [first definition of `every`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9eb8bd6c5bcecb962a1caa0b0f129ab3f77a9924/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1216)

Comment: @Guaycuru - `every` has two overloads. When you hover over `every` in an editor, it probably only shows one of them. The definition linked by @Matthieu shows both.

Comment: @TobiasS.Oh you are right, that's interesting. Any idea why `every` needs those 2 signatures but `some` needs only one?

Comment: @Guaycuru - I am wondering that too. I believe the reasoning is the following: The overload *without* type predicate is chosen when the user gives the `predicate` an explicit type predicate. The overload *with* type predicate is chosen when the user explicitly provides a generic type to `every`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a current limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#44373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373).

---

TypeScript has long had a problem with calling methods on a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of array types.  Originally you couldn't call unions-of-functions at all, because the compiler didn't know how to merge multiple signatures into a single usable one.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#7294](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294):

```
// Before TS3.3:
declare const arr: string[] | number[];
arr.some(() => true); // error
arr.map(() => 1); // error
arr.every(() => true); // error
```

---

TypeScript 3.3 introduced [some support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for doing this with [microsoft/TypeScript#29011](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011), by accepting an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the parameters from the union members.

But this support was only added for relatively simple cases where at most one member of the union was a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function and at most one member of the union was an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function.  So if the array methods you were merging were generic or overloaded, you still couldn't call them.  So there was an improvement, but some methods like `map()` still weren't callable. See [microsoft/TypeScript#36390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390):

```
// TS3.3
declare const arr: string[] | number[];
arr.some(() => true); // okay
arr.map(() => 1); // error
arr.every(() => true); // okay
```

---

At some point it was decided to add a generic overload to `every()` so that it could act as a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates); see [microsoft/TypeScript#38200](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38200).  This is useful, but unfortunately it means that `every()` also stopped working on unions of array types.  This was released with TypeScript 4.0:

```
// TS 4.0
declare const arr: string[] | number[];
arr.some(() => true); // okay
arr.map(() => 1); // error
arr.every(() => true); // error
```

---

For TypeScript 4.2 [microsoft/TypeScript#31023](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31023) was merged, which added some support for calling unions of generic call signatures, as long as the generic type parameters were identical.  But for overloaded call signatures, the problem persists:

```
// TS 4.2+
declare const arr: string[] | number[];
arr.some(() => true); // okay
arr.map(() => 1); // okay
arr.every(() => true); // error
```

And that's where we are currently.

---

Maybe at some point, microsoft/TypeScript#44373 will be addressed.  It's not obvious what the right thing to do here is for unions of overloaded methods in general.  I think it's possible someone might want to target just the unions-of-array case by automatically widening to a readonly-array-of-unions, since doing that manually is the workaround I usually suggest, and it's fairly safe:

```
const arr2: readonly (string | number)[] = arr; // okay
arr2.every(() => true); // okay
```

But for now, this doesn't happen.

[Playgorund link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3rGAuemMAligOYDaAuvAD7woCuAtgEYgxUDcAsAFA4A6NEiYgAFGICU8ALwA+eBhgMQkzvAD0G+OxhIY8NgDN9CACoBlAMwCrfQUygAHCdPnwAjGs3bd+wyAmcPCWACwCAEz2MDACIABu7ACerrIKSireWjox-samIda22CjABBiwGCSk8ADuRBgAFoXhAAx8fMjoWDgR+HBQwKgQSfBihNW09MxsMJJUstgx6tlIANZQSdEwEXGJMClSaYrKqiva65tAA)

Answer (score 1):

That has to do with the [definition of `every()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9eb8bd6c5bcecb962a1caa0b0f129ab3f77a9924/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1207)

```
every<S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): this is readonly S[];
```

In a case of your union the signature become's

```
{
  <S extends number>(predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): true; 
  (predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): this is S[]; 
} |
{ 
   <S extends string>(predicate: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): true;
    (predicate: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): this is S[];
}
```

You can see that the predicates have incompatible types.

Comment: so why are they incompatible :) ?

Comment: Yes, that's my followup question as well: Why does `every()` have those 2 overloads while `some()` does not? And also, is there a way to narrow my call to `every()` so it doesn't error anymore?

Answer (score 1):

As we already discussed in the comments, `every` has an overload containing a generic function with a type predicate while `some` has no such things.

Why are the function signatures *"incompatible"* now?

- Its definitely related to the fact that they are generic. I have yet to find a definitive answer. Maybe @jcalz knows a satisfying explanation :)

Why is `every` generic and has a type predicate?

- Contrary to `some`, calling `every` can have an effect on the type of the array. If you have an array like

  ```
  const arr: (string | number)[] = []
  ```

  Calling `every` on it and checking if every element is a `number` *should* also change the type of the resulting array.

  ```
  const arr2 = arr.every((e): e is number => typeof e === "number")
  // arr2 should be number[]
  ```

  This is only possible to achieve with *type predicates*. And to allow type predicates to have an effect here, `every` must be generic. (Otherwise the type predicate would be ignored by `every`)

---

So what can you do about it?

I would suggest changing the type of `input` to an intersection of `(number[] | string[])` and `(number | string)[]`. This may look weird but it does fix the error here.

```
function doEverythingWithArray(
  input: (number[] | string[]) & (number | string)[]
): boolean {
  return input.every(i => doSomething(i));
}
```

The function also remains callable as before.

```
// works as before
doEverythingWithArray(["a", "b", "c"])
doEverythingWithArray(["a", "b", "c"] as string[])
doEverythingWithArray([0, 1, 2])
doEverythingWithArray([0, 1, 2] as number[])

// fails
doEverythingWithArray([0, 1, "a"])
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgCYIMoILYFMYAWcEA5gBTEAOYMAXMhGNgEa4BOAPgM4xvEkBKeswQIANrgCGKAN7BkyOCGQUI1GMgC825ABYATMg4dFamlp0ByA5YHI5ChW3xg2KXmFwBuecgC+yLhiXLj2vk4ubsggksHevn7AiaCQsIgo6Fh4hPwA6nCEAIJsbJIAnqrq9Iws7ADaALrcvPyNQsgi4lKyvs4wrihUNAB0XDi4FFoAfGiY4zmkFAICPsng0PBIswCiAG7sZQsk+UUl5ZU09GQ1rGyNRsg8fKRtyABkKjfsD0-8Am3CUQSaRhCL9KJDGDDXD7NgVODTWZZfBERZwZarYDAdB7A5HE4EYqlCp1ABEklJABpkKTmFSaVBSQ0BNiELi4fiCoSziTyfTafzGQ1kJIuI8Wi9maz2YdUccuUTznUAAzUgCM1P0UpxsNleQVPLIKvVmuFooYTFubSxOrxcoJipJquQGppFOZyAA9J7opI4MEsUA)

Comment: `const arr2 = arr.every((e): e is number => typeof e === "number")`
Isn't `arr2 === true` given that `every()` returns `true` or `false`?
Which also means that `every()` does not (and should not) mutate the original array

Comment: It does not mutate the Array. But it changes the *type* of the Array :)